# Comparator for MultiSet.Entry and Generics

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I need a Comparator for a guava MultiSet.Entry, for sorting by count first and String second. However, I get compiler problems and I think I get something with the generics wrong.

This compiles:

```
Comparator<Multiset.Entry<String>> comparator() {
    return Comparator.comparing(Multiset.Entry::getCount);
}
```

However, this not:

```
Comparator<Multiset.Entry<String>> comparator() {
    return Comparator.comparing(Multiset.Entry::getCount).thenComparing(Multiset.Entry::getElement);
}
```

```
Error: java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T,U
    (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      method getCount in interface com.google.common.collect.Multiset.Entry cannot be applied to given types
        required: no arguments
        found: java.lang.Object
        reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

If I combine Comparators e.g. for a String, I obviously don't have a similar problem.

```
Comparator<String> comparator2() {
    return Comparator.comparing(String::length).thenComparing(String::toString);
}
```

What am I missing here, and how can I get it to work?

(Note: I'm aware there might be different approaches with Guava, but I want to understand the problem I get here.)

Comment: I don't claim to understand why it's necessary, but you can get these `thenComparing` chains to compile by adding explicit type arguments for the first method call. `Comparator.<Multiset.Entry<String>, Integer>comparing(Multiset.Entry::getCount).thenComparing(Multiset.Entry::getElement);`

Comment: You should also use comparingInt() for the first comparison: `return Comparator.<Multiset.Entry<String>>comparingInt(Multiset.Entry::getCount).thenComparing(Multiset.Entry::getElement);`

Comment: comparingInt() makes sense, but it still requires an explicit type argument. Why is it necessary with MultiSet.Entry, but not with String?

Comment: Probably because one is generic and the other is not. I don't know enough of the compiler inference to know in advance when it can and when it can't infer. I just add type arguments when I see it can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* it's because of how type targeting (a form of Java inferencing) works in conjunction with the dot functionality programming used in your code (you can read about target types [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#target-typing) in the java docs, specifically the section called: `Target Types and Method Arguments`).

In very short, if I have something like this:

```
List<String> list = new List<>();
```

The target type here is `List<String>` so Java (8) realises that the new list that you are creating is assigned to and should be of type `List<String>`, therefore the type can be inferred and you do not have to specify the type parameter.

What it comes down to for the first snippest that does compile is: The section of code `Comparator.comparing(Multiset.Entry::getCount);` returns a type of `Comparator<T>`, this result is immediately assigned to the return type of the method (i.e. the method's return type is the target type). The compiler can infer the type since the target type is the return type of the method `comparator`, which you explicitly defined/captured in the method signature as `Comparator<Multiset.Entry<String>>`. The `T` in `Comparator<T>` can thus be inferred.

In the second snippet of code (that does not compile and require the explicit type witness argument - the explicit bit in the <> for the method call), you are using the dot operator that chains methods. This means that the second part `thenComparing(Multiset.Entry::getElement)` is applied to the result of the first part `Comparator.comparing(Multiset.Entry::getCount)`.

The second part can infer the type from the target type, since the result of the second part is what is returned by the method, so the target type of the second part is similar to the above case that did compile - the method return type was captured and defined, thus it can infer this.

But for the first part, the target type is uncertain, since it is not being assigned to some type with actual types. According to the Comparator API, `Comparator<T>` is what is returned by that function, but since it doesn't know what type it is going to be assigned to specifically, you need to supply the type witness and explicitly specify that when it returns `Comparator<T>` the `T` should be (in your case) `Multiset.Entry<String>`.

Comment: P.s. I do not know much about Guava - so not sure if Guava has an influence on how the inference works or not.

Comment: Ah, I obviously wasn't aware of all the implications of type inference in conjunction with lambdas. Thanks for the detailed answer, and I'm sure it has nothing to do with Guava in particular.

Comment: Given the message "actual and formal argument lists differ in length", this can't be right. At least, I don't understand where the wrongly-sized argument list comes from.

Comment: @maaartinus As far as I know: This method reference is insufficient for type inference, and since there is no target type (explained in answer), types can't be inferred. Read [here](). The method reference `ObjectType::instanceMethod` converts to `Function<ObjectType, ReturnType>, but ObjectType here is `Multiset.Entry`, which is raw type  without <> and gets passed as Object, and thus mistaken as argument type for Function<T, R>. A target type would help infer object type `Multiset.Entry<String>' avoiding this. But due to dot, the first part does not have target type to use to infer <> part.

Comment: [Here is that link](https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx#instance-method-reference-of-an-object-of-a-particular-type). Lambda expressions and method references are discussed here. The method reference in the question code is a "instance method reference of an object of a particular type", i.e. a non static method for a particular class. An instance of the class is passed when the method is called, but a generic class that can't be inferred properly causes trouble.